# InvokeScriptAsync not launching script

Tags: webview, uwp

I have an UWP app and I'm trying to get a script invoked from a WebView. The NavigationCompleted event raises and my javascript is included (I think) in the page but the script isn't executed.

Here's my C# code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    readonly WebView _webView = new WebView();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Facebook.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/"));
        _webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_OnNavigationCompleted;
        _webView.ScriptNotify += WebView_OnScriptNotify;
    }

    private async void WebView_OnNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        await _webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
        {
            "alert('HEY');" + 
            "window.external.notify('%%' + location.href);"
        });
    }

    private void WebView_OnScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        var url = e.Value;
    }
}
```

Also, I added http://www.facebook.com and https://www.facebook.com to my package manifest Content Uris list (include with all WinRT access).

I can't get the alert popping, same for the notify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [WebView docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView), `alert` doesn't work in a WebView control.

For Script Notify to work you need to add the page to the app manifest as well:

> To enable an external web page to fire the ScriptNotify event when calling window.external.notify, you must include the page's Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) in the ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest.

And:

> The URIs in this list must use HTTPS

So, try navigating to the https site instead.

Worst case, you can use a web allowed object in order to communicate back to your app as that can be injected in all cases.

Comment: Thus, if the website doesn't support https, it will not work?

Comment: If it's not https, you'd need to use the `AddWebAllowedObject` method to add a class that has the `AllowForWeb` attribute.  Then you can use eval to inject code that calls a method on the C# class and have it call an event which you register to in your main application's code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this possibility though it seems more complicated than just injecting some javascript in the page.